# Discord Embed sending with a custom message typed by user

Tags: json, discord

How would I go about creating a Discord embed but something like this:
The author name is shown
The title is shown
The "description" of the embed is what the user has typed in their message after the prefix which is ;;ruling

So for example,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6uep.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Please provide a [mcve], as text not as image.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working version of what you want

Usage: `;;ruling send-embed "My Title" "And my description"`

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('error' => console.log);

bot.on('message', message => {
  let prefix = ';;ruling';
  let sender = message.author;
  let msg = message.content;
  let cont = msg.split(' ');
  let args = cont.slice(1);
  let cmd = msg.startsWith(prefix) ? cont[0].slice(prefix.length).toUpperCase() : undefined;

  if (cmd === 'SEND-EMBED' || cmd === 'SENDEMBED') {
    if (!args[0]) {
      message.channel.send('Please specify your message');
      return;
    }
    let tokens = [].concat.apply([], args.join(' ').split('"').map(function(v,i){
       return i%2 ? v : v.split(' ')
    })).filter(Boolean);
    message.channel.send({embed:{
      author:{
        name: sender.username,
        icon_url: sender.avatarURL,
      },
      title: tokens[0],
      description: tokens[1],
      color: 0x2ff37a
    }});
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```